# PrismJS package not automatically highlighting markdown

Tags: typescript, next.js, markdown, prismjs

I'm using [Prism](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prismjs) to highlight my markdown code snippets. I am calling `Prism.highlightAll()`, and I have a `<pre>`-tagged section. Yet, it is not highlighting my syntax.

Here's my component with the `useEffect` hook which attempts to highlight (I checked, it's being called):

```
const ArticlePage: NextPage<{ article: Article }> = ({ article }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    Prism.highlightAll(); // <-- HERE IT IS BEING CALLED
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className={styles.box}>
      <h1 className="mb-5 text-6xl leading-1 font-extrabold">
        {article.title}
      </h1>
      <ReactMarkdown>{markdown}</ReactMarkdown> // <-- What I'm trying to highlight
    </div>
  );
};
```

My `markdown` is pulling trivially from here:

````
  const markdown: string = "```dart\nprint('hello');\nprint('world');\n```";
````

Here are my relevant imports:

```
import Prism from "prismjs";
import { useEffect } from "react";

require("prismjs/components/prism-javascript");

require("prismjs/components/prism-dart");

require("prismjs/components/prism-css");

require("prismjs/components/prism-jsx");
```

I am also using `getServerSideProps` to return the actual markdown I need to render (this example I hard-code it for brevity):

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  const slug = context.query.slug;
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://MY_WEBSITE_URL/article/" + slug
  );
  const article: Article = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      article,
    },
  };
};

export default ArticlePage;
```

Here is what the inspect-element looks like:

[image]

Here's the webpage representation (no syntax highlighting!):

[image]

If it's helpful, I'm using Typescript, TailwindCSS, NextJS, and pulling from a Heroku web server built in Rust (Actix-Web).

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Looking at the screenshot of what the HTML looks like in "inspect element" I would say your Prism code is working just fine. Are you sure you are loading a corresponding stylesheet?

Comment: I just figured it out last night — I was loading my stylesheet at the top. What worked was sticking it inside the `useEffect` hook! I'll post an answer when I'm allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Instead of placing the imports at the top of your file, put them inside the `UseEffect` hook:

```
require("prismjs/components/prism-javascript");

require("prismjs/components/prism-dart");

require("prismjs/components/prism-css");

require("prismjs/components/prism-jsx");
```